# assigning new id/class to a list item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a Jquery Sortable list that replaces two items with one another. Each `<li>` has a unique `id` and `name` and the values are obtained from a php file.

HTML sample:

```
<ul id="sections" class="ui-sortable">
   <li id="one" name="one" value="<?php echo $forms[0]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[0]; ?>">one</li>
   <li id="onea" name="one_a" value="<?php echo $forms[1]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[1]; ?>"> two</li>
   <li id="oneb" name="one_b" value="<?php echo $forms[2]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[2]; ?>">three</li>
   <li id="two" name="two" value="<?php echo $forms[3]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[3]; ?>"> four  </li>
   <li id="twoa" name="two_a" value="<?php echo $forms[4]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[4]; ?>">five</li>
   <li id="twob" name="two_b" value="<?php echo $forms[5]; ?>" class="<?php echo $forms[5]; ?>"> six </li>
</ul>
```

the include() php file (sample):

```
<?php
$forms = array('fish','bird','tiger','dog','cat','elephant');
?>
```

Now using the `$( "#sections" ).sortable({...` method i'm able to for example replace `<li>six</li>` with `<li>two</li>`. In this case that would mean swapping a `bird` with an `elephant`.

The problem is when I utilise this in a `<form>` application and `POST` it to a `example.php` file the `$_POST` variable is posting its original order.

So in this case `$_POST['one-a'];` is still returning `bird` not `elephant`. I used the inspect element on my browser and saw that the `id` and `name` is moving with the swap. So `#onea` and `#twob` moved aswell.

What i want to do is keep the `id` and `name` order in place and only have the `value` change when a swap is made.

So in this scenario `elephant` would be posted for its new `id` of `onea` and `name` of `one_a`.

Is that possible?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you pass inside tha value element the name "bird" with an underscore and a position number? this way you can solve your trouble no?

Comment: try to sort it from php itself. like $form = sort($form);

Comment: This appen however because manipulating the DOM won't reflex on form submit. It works with Ajax(s) call.

Comment: The value attribute was deprecated in html 4 and can only be used with an li as a child of an ol in html5 - [See this](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li.attrs.value)

Comment: @Pete I also tried with `<input>` and `<div>` tags, still the same thing kept happening. @Goiku so you mean `<?php echo $forms[1;]?>"_2"` or am I not following you correctly. @CJ Ramki I don't understand what you mean in letting php sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilise a workaround in order to get the current `value`. Using Jquery and `$.ajax()` I posted the `data` after various `if/else` statements.

So basically it was something like this;

JS:

```
var firstone = $('#sections #one');
var firstoneextra = firstone.hasClass("ui-selected");

if (firstoneextra){
    var newone = //take the new selected value.
}else{
    var newone = //keep the value it has already.
}...
```

and the when processing the data through an `$.ajax()` call;

(sample):

```
data: 'one=' + newone ...
```

It would would either `POST` the new value if it was selected, or `POST` the value it already had to begin with.